# something wrong in an edge case for chessboard?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, chessboard

There's a combination of three features in `chessboard` that's doing something unexpected (typesetting some characters in nullfont):  curvemove, marking a not-in-a-single-file move, and a non-integer boardfontsize.  Any ideas for workarounds to avoid shedding these characters?

```
\documentclass{article}

% Running this code generates nullfont characters.  From the log:
%    Missing character: There is no . ("2E) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 7 ("37) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 5 ("35) in font nullfont!

\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
  \chessboard[
    pgfstyle=curvemove,   % with pgfstyle=straightmove, the problem goes away.
    boardfontsize=9.75pt, % with boardfontsize=10pt, the problem goes away.
    markmoves={a2-b3}     % with markmoves={a2-a4} or {a2-a3}, the problem goes away.
    % Note:  with markmoves={a2-b2,a2-c2,a2-d2,a2-f2}, a version of the issue persists
    %        (typesetting ".25" or ".5" or ".75" in nullfont), though markmoves={a2-e2}
    %        seems totally fine (possibly because of divisibility by four).
  ]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: it is a bug in chessboard. It uses the boardfontsize for a division, but with the tex primitive \divide only integers are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following patch. The next chessboard version will then contain it.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Running this code generates nullfont characters.  From the log:
%    Missing character: There is no . ("2E) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 7 ("37) in font nullfont!
%    Missing character: There is no 5 ("35) in font nullfont!

\usepackage{chessboard,etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\newcommand\board@divide@NN[2]{%
 \dim_set:Nn#1 {#1*\dim_ratio:nn{1pt}{#2}}}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\patchcmd\board@pgf@extractangle
  {\divide \len@board@tempy by \strip@pt\len@board@tempx\relax}
  {\board@divide@NN\len@board@tempy\len@board@tempx}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \chessboard[
    pgfstyle=curvemove,   % with pgfstyle=straightmove, the problem goes away.
    boardfontsize=9.75pt, % with boardfontsize=10pt, the problem goes away.
    markmoves={a2-b3}     % with markmoves={a2-a4} or {a2-a3}, the problem goes away.
    % Note:  with markmoves={a2-b2,a2-c2,a2-d2,a2-f2}, a version of the issue persists
    %        (typesetting ".25" or ".5" or ".75" in nullfont), though markmoves={a2-e2}
    %        seems totally fine (possibly because of divisibility by four).
  ]
\end{document}
```